# Python: Find out how positive a number is with respect to 0

Tags: python, list, numpy

Let's say I have the below list:

```
o =[[-0.90405713, -0.86583093, -0.14048125]]
```

How do I find out how positive each element of `o[0]` is?

So,by looking at this I know that `-0.14048125` is the most "positive" with respect to `0` on the number line. Is there a way to do this via a python code?

Comment: `max(somellist)` ?

Comment: Isn't it simply geting max value from a list?

Comment: What do you mean by "most positive with respect to 0" Smallest absolute value?

Comment: Do you want the biggest value or the closest to `0`?

Comment: Closing as duplicate. Will reopen if question is edited. In the current state, it's just a duplicate.

Comment: No element is more "positive" than any other in your list.

Comment: Is `0` kind of the most positive with all respect due to him? If yes I have absolutely 0 reason to be negative about my bank statement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `max()`

```
>>> o =[-0.90405713,-0.86583093,-0.14048125]
>>> max(o)
-0.14048125
```

Comment: Oh man! Thanks so much! It just didn't strike me to think of this. For some reason I was approaching this with respect to the number line and was thinking that I needed to do some mathematical calculations

Answer (score 3):

If you want the value closest to 0, you could use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) with [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs) as key:

```
>>> o =[-0.90405713,-0.86583093,-0.14048125,3]
>>> min(o, key=abs)
-0.14048125
```

Comment: nice but that doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: To be honest, I probably don't understand the question. My answer is just an alternative to the obvious `max(o)`. It does work fine with the provided example, though.

Comment: let's wait for the OP to edit the question.